# How can I remove the duplicate suggestions from Bugzilla?

Tags: bug-report, bugzilla

The Bugzilla duplicate suggestions are useless for me, since I'm the only tester and I know my own bugs quite well.

The list is shown on the `http://bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi` page (where  `bugzilla` is the name of the Bugzilla server.

I have tried:

- finding a setting in Bugzilla that's responsible for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [Greasemonkey (Firefox)](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and add a user script that removes the part of the webpage that is not relevant:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Remove possible duplicates
// @namespace   bugzilla
// @description Remove possible duplicates
// @include     http://bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
var row = document.getElementById('possible_duplicates_container');
row.innerHTML = '<p>Duplicates deactivated by Greasemonkey.</p>';
```

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal: thanks. And I have to wait for 2 days, unfortunately